# On which Stack Exchange site can I ask a question about aMule?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to know on which Stack Exchange site I can ask a question about [aMule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMule) (or eMule, for Windows Users).

Comment: Do you mean this http://wiki.amule.org/wiki/AMule Some more explanation or even an example question would be helpful If on windows try http://superuser.com or for mac https://apple.stackexchange.com/ or for Linux https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think I will try apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is software: *"[aMule is a free peer-to-peer file sharing utility that works with the EDonkey network and the Kad network, offering similar features to eMule and adding others such as GeoIP (country flags).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMule)"*